# Promotion isnt being applied in basket?

Tags: promotions, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to create a pretty simple promotion rule where if a customer buys 3 of a specific item they will get 1 free, The screen shots below show the setup of my promotion:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see it all looks in order but when I add 4 of the same item to a basket and check it doesn't apply the discount, can someone please help as i am not sure if i have missed a configuration option. Also is there a way to add an item to the bask if they have ordered something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to get result. You should test and try every combination of rules to build particular rule, don't hurt, repeat until to get some result. (Trying and testing is free)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your action tab currently looks wrong. It is looking for a product with the SKU "ew5532,xxx,yyy". What you probably wanted is to use 
`SKU is one of ew5532, xxx, yyy` so it will be applied to ew5532 as well as xxx and yyy.